# Why isn't md-xsmall-hide class hiding the div?

Tags: vue-material

I have the following...

```
 <div class="md-toolbar-row">
      <div class="md-toolbar-section-start">
      </div>
      <div class="md-toolbar-row md-toolbar-offset md-xsmall-hide">
          <span class="md-display-1">{{title}}</span>
      </div>
 </div>
```

But when I try to run, it doesn't hide. I double checked that the class was being added.

[image]

How do I get the hide to work?

Answer (score 0):

Put the `md-xsmall-hide` class on its own nested `div` so it doesn't get overridden by the toolbar styles. See fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/0hrd8sbw/